# FormData.append and .set do not add entries

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the entries from a `FormData` object using `append`. I have also tried `set`. When I attempt to `console.log` the entries it's empty.

```js
const fd = new FormData()
fd.append('firstname', 'Bob')
fd.append('surname', 'Hammond')
fd.append('birthday', new Date(1, 1, 2018))

const entries = fd.entries()
console.log(entries)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert `entries` (an [iterable](https://javascript.info/iterable)) to an Array with [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```js
const fd = new FormData()
fd.set('firstname', 'Bob')
fd.set('surname', 'Hammond')
fd.append('birthday', new Date(1, 1, 2018))

const entries = fd.entries()
console.log([...entries])
```

You can also use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

```js
const fd = new FormData()
fd.set('firstname', 'Bob')
fd.set('surname', 'Hammond')
fd.append('birthday', new Date(1, 1, 2018))

const entries = fd.entries()
console.log(Array.from(entries))
```

You could use a [`for of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop to get each entry separately as `entries` is an iterable object.

```js
const fd = new FormData()
fd.set('firstname', 'Bob')
fd.set('surname', 'Hammond')
fd.append('birthday', new Date(1, 1, 2018))

const entries = fd.entries()
for(let item of entries){
  console.log(item);
}
```

Comment: what is triple dot indicate in console.log([...entries])

Comment: @KrishnaJonnalagadda It's [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Answer (score 0):

Entries returns iterator, you can call next() to get next value:

```
entries.next();
```

Or place it in a loop.

```
for (let entry of entries) {
    console.log(entry);
}
```

Or convert to array:

```
Array.from(entries);
```